# IntelliJ / Android Studio - Replace all as refactor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, refactoring

I want to change (Replace All - ctrl + R) text occurrences at the same time refactoring it. Is it possible? Something like: (ctrl + R) + (shift + f6)

Comment: Makes no sense, refactoring understands code and replaces occurrences only where needed, while Replace All is dumb and replaces all the occurrences.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I need to use it with resources files in the android project. I have strings.xml where I need to replace all occurrences of the word "standings" in attributes name="..." . But I already use this strings in my project so at the same time it should be refactored in others files (e.g. layouts...).

Comment: @CrazyCoder How is that "it makes no sense"? Maybe it isn't implemented, but as a feature request makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Replace in Path" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).
It works as simple Replace All in whole project. That means in some scenarios (check my comment to CrazyCoder) we have to use it few times (e.q. one time on resources files, the second time on code files).

Comment: That's a bit dangerous, since there maybe matches that aren't intended to be changed, for example similar ids in different scopes. Granted, you can check these by hand one by one before replacing them, but that defeats the whole purpose of automating the process.